# How to take screenshot of a particular div in react js ? I have used "use-screenshot-hook" package but it is taking the screenshot of whole page

Tags: html, reactjs

```
const ref = createRef(null); 
const { image, takeScreenshot } = useScreenshot();     
const imgStyle = { height: height, width: width }    
      const getImage = () => takeScreenshot({ref});
      const downloadImage = () => {
        var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
        FileSaver.saveAs(`${image}`, "image.jpg");
      }
            <button onClick={getImage}>
              Take screenshot
            </button>
    
            <button onClick={downloadImage}>Download</button>
            <div  ref={ref}>
              <img id="scream" style={imgStyle} src={url} height="448" width="100%" ref={imgRef}></img> //imgRef is for zoom functionality
            </div>
```

I need to take screenshot of image  (along with icons dragged over it from another component). I used ref but its still taking screenshot of whole page

Comment: You have `ref.current` in `getImage()` and `ref={imgRef}` for the `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `ref` is in your code, since you never use it in the posted html. But assuming it is a ref to the `div` you want, the way to pass it to the `takeScreenshot` method is

```
const getImage = () => takeScreenshot({ ref });
```

(*according to their [API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-screenshot-hook)*)

Comment: passed ref into screenshot method, still not working

Comment: @aReactBeginner do not use `createRef` in a function component, use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: OK noted Thanks...still its not working......any other suggestion to take screenshot of a particular portion in a page                                                                                                                    .....In my scenario I have an image and I am dragging some icons over it and have to save the image along with the dragged icons

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem by using `ref` and passing the `ref` to the particular `div`:

```
const imageRef = useRef(null);

const { image, takeScreenshot, isLoading, clear } = useScreenshot({ref:imageRef});

<div ref={imageRef}></div>
```